# retrieving the last id value of the productcode field

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to retrieve the last id value asscoaited  productcode field

[image]

I have tried following ways of retrieving the max id of the ProductCode

```
select MAX(id) from code ORDER by productcode desc;
```

i get the 'id' as 25 which doesn't have "productcode" associated with it.

```
select MAX(id) from code ORDER by id where productcode is NOT Null;
```

i receive syntax error for the same

i only need the max(id) that is associated with productcode i.e..,id= 23;

Answer (score 2):

```
select MAX(id) from code WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(ProductCode)>=1 ORDER by ProductCodedesc;
```

would work. you can also have the condition test for the empty string.

Hope this helps! let me know if you need anything else

note: checking for null in this case would result in false positives as well, since your values for empty fields seems to be literally empty strings.. not null values

limit was indeed not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
SELECT * FROM code WHERE ProductCode != "" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I tried it and it works for me.
If I am wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

use not null check in your condition

```
select MAX(id) from code 
where productcode is not null or productcode != ''
ORDER by productcode desc;
```

Comment: the result i get is 25.

Comment: I think it should be `and` instead of `or`

Comment: and condition will check for both have true .....but in case of or condition it will get execute when it finds first